# Adding text to a field when clicked

Tags: javascript, field

I want to have a list of words that when clicked are added to a form to be submitted.

Something like:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3

[         ] (an empty field.)
```

When Word1 and Word3 are clicked, the field is populated with

```
Word1 Word2 Word3

[Word1 Word3]
```

Is this even possible?  I feel like it should be possible with javascript.
How can you approach doing this?

Comment: Totally possible. You would need to wrap each word in a tag (a or span perhaps) then it's simply a matter of listening for click event, grabbing innerhtml and appending to the input

Comment: I'm giving it a go one step at a time, for the first time ever I'm attempting to dosomething beyond cut and paste here.

Comment: I think I'll cover the first part and I can add info to a form when submitted, not sure how to send the html in the span to the field and have it displayed before submissio.

Comment: In otherwords Steve, thank you for telling me its possible.

Comment: No problem. If you get stuck on something, edit your question with the code you have and I'm sure you will get help. Questions without code dont do so well here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use javascript and either links or buttons like so.

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('word_field').value=document.getElementById('word_field').value+' Word1';" value="Word1"/><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('word_field').value=document.getElementById('word_field').value+' Word2';">Word 2</a><br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="word_field"/>
```

Comment: Complete **ugh**. Get those inline _onclick_ handlers out of there. Tagging the selectable words with `<span class="selectable">Word 1</span>` as Wycliff suggests is far _far_ better. Keep your content (html), style (css), and behavior (js) separated.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you very much, this is exactly the functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Set up on click listeners for the elements. You can declare them with one class. On click, get the data from the element and place into result element like so:

$('.clickable').click(function(){         $("#result").append($(this).val());
    });

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p214xntf/)